# Asset transform messing with color

Tags: image, image-transforms, imagick

I have a client with *very* stringent concerns over acurate color in thier images.

They have noticed that image resized from Craft have some dramatic color discrepancies, which I have verified. It's nothing you'd probably notice in a regular photo, but these are actual fabric swatch images, so the color is crucial.

Anyway - first thing I verified was that Imagick was being used, which it is.

However, when I look at the file info, it still says something about `gd-jpeg` which concerning...not sure if that is just a red herring though.

```
❯ file resized-720.jpeg
resized-720.jpeg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, comment: "CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJ"
```

Is this more appropriately posted as an issue for https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine?

Comment: Do you get the same color discrepancy if you use Imagick from the command line?

Comment: I don't. So I manually set `'imageDriver' => 'imagick'`, cleared the cache, and then they looked good on the server (also no gd-jpeg) header.

Comment: However, even if I take the imageDriver setting out now, it still works...so it seems at some point when the images were created Craft didn't think I had ImageMagick installed.

Comment: Huh... weird.   ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, the images were created thinking Imagick wasn't installed. Clearing the cache forced the images to be recreated and seems to have fixed it.